# Transaction Log backup in MSSQL's HADR

Tags: sql-server

I'm a resident developer who is voluntold to be a database admin of MSSQL 2016.  Please bear with me as I'm still trying to self taught the art of DB admin.

I recently setup a DR solution using the architecture (Always On High Availability Group) below and things are working well for me.  All databases are synchronizing.

[image]

In my primary data center, I have two nodes (active & passive) that share the same disk (Log disk, data, ect..).  Currently I see the following on my active node, they're were setup there by my predecessors.

1. All databases are all in full recovery mode.
2. It has a Full Backup maintenance plan where a full DB backup is done at 12am daily.
3. It has a Log Backup maintenance plan where transaction logs are backed up every 5 minutes.

I understand that Always On High Availability Group use transaction log to sync data between the Primary Data node and the Disaster Recovery Node.  Can I disable the transaction log backup in #3?

Do you see any issue if I do not backup my transaction log at a 5 minutes interval?  Can I use my DR node as a "backup" in case something went wrong instead of restoring my database using our last daily backup and then procedurally  restore the entire transaction log backup from that day?

Comment: What if your "went wrong'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I use my DR node as a "backup" in case something went wrong instead of restoring my database using our last daily backup and then procedurally restore the entire transaction log backup from that day?

No.  All changes, including ones you might like to undo, are automatically written to your AG secondaries.  You should take log backups on *exactly one* replica and all the backups should go to a single location.  You can configure a [Backup Preference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-backup-on-availability-replicas-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) to help make sure that 1) backups are being taken, and 2) they are taken on your preferred node if it is available.